# Rewrite url for Angular app within sub-folder

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got an Angular app using html5mode, but it's currently sitting within a sub-folder of a site: http://somesite.com/za/

So I've managed to rewrite the url to direct to my assets folder correctly, but I'm still getting 404s when I hit refresh or navigate directly to a page.

---

So this works: http://somesite.com/za/assets/js/bundle.js

This doesn't work, 404: http://somesite.com/za/home

---

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
#This apparently creates a redirect loop for angular
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(za/.*) /za/index.html [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*/)*([^/.]+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png||css|js))$ za/assets/$1 [R=301,L,NC]

AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
```

So where is the rewrite failing to redirect to index.html when I hit or refresh a page?

Comment: I don't think you need a rewrite rule you only need to set the base tag in the head of your HTML: `<base href="/za/" />`

Comment: @Michelem, base tag is already set: <base href="/za/">

Answer (score 4):

Solved it with a more elegant rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
   RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

   RewriteRule ^(.*) /za/index.html [NC,L]
```

However, this does give read access to other files and directories, so it can have security issues.